# Scaling a single continuous variable

Tags: mixed-model, data-transformation

I have a basic question. I know you have to scale your variables (fixed effects) when you have several continuous fixed effects, to be able to compare them. However, if I only have one continuous variable and the rest of my fixed effects are factors, should I scale my continuous variable? I'm centering, but I'm unsure about scaling.

Thank you,

Laura

Comment: In general, you don't have to scale variables to compare them!  That is a special kind of comparison with such limited utility it's rarely described in posts here.  Would you mind, then, telling us what kind of procedure you are using?